# RGB to YIQ and back in python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision

I had a task needed to convert RGB to YIQ and back using only simple functions (in lib: plt cv2 np)

What I got is the "naive" code solution:

```
def transformRGB2YIQ(imgRGB: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Converts an RGB image to YIQ color space
    :param imgRGB: An Image in RGB
    :return: A YIQ in image color space
    """

    yiq_from_rgb = np.array([[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],
                             [0.59590059, -0.27455667, -0.32134392],
                             [0.21153661, -0.52273617, 0.31119955]])

    YIQ = np.dot(imgRGB.reshape(-1, 3), yiq_from_rgb).reshape(imgRGB.shape)

    return YIQ

    pass


def transformYIQ2RGB(imgYIQ: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Converts an YIQ image to RGB color space
    :param imgYIQ: An Image in YIQ
    :return: A RGB in image color space
    """
    yiq_from_rgb = np.array([[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],
                             [0.59590059, -0.27455667, -0.32134392],
                             [0.21153661, -0.52273617, 0.31119955]])
    rgb_from_yiq = np.linalg.inv(yiq_from_rgb)
    RGB = np.dot(imgYIQ.reshape(-1, 3), rgb_from_yiq).reshape(imgYIQ.shape)

    return RGB
    pass
```

I have tried using np.dot and to re-shape the img so I could multiply it by the matrix, like that:

[image]

but no luck there... I got the wrong answer.

Also tried:

```
def transformRGB2YIQ(imgRGB: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Converts an RGB image to YIQ color space
    :param imgRGB: An Image in RGB
    :return: A YIQ in image color space
    """

    YIQ = np.ndarray(imgRGB.shape)

    YIQ[:, :, 0] = 0.299 * imgRGB[:, :, 0] + 0.587 * imgRGB[:, :, 1] + 0.114 * imgRGB[:, :, 2]
    YIQ[:, :, 1] = 0.59590059 * imgRGB[:, :, 0] + (-0.27455667) * imgRGB[:, :, 1] + (-0.32134392) * imgRGB[:, :, 2]
    YIQ[:, :, 2] = 0.21153661 * imgRGB[:, :, 0] + (-0.52273617) * imgRGB[:, :, 1] + 0.31119955 * imgRGB[:, :, 2]

    return YIQ

    pass


def transformYIQ2RGB(imgYIQ: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Converts an YIQ image to RGB color space
    :param imgYIQ: An Image in YIQ
    :return: A RGB in image color space
    """
    yiq_from_rgb = np.array([[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],
                             [0.59590059, -0.27455667, -0.32134392],
                             [0.21153661, -0.52273617, 0.31119955]])
    rgb_from_yiq = np.linalg.inv(yiq_from_rgb)

    RGB = np.ndarray(imgYIQ.shape)
    RGB[:, :, 0] = 1.00000001 * imgYIQ[:, :, 0] + 0.95598634 * imgYIQ[:, :, 1] + 0.6208248 * imgYIQ[:, :, 2]
    RGB[:, :, 1] = 0.99999999 * imgYIQ[:, :, 0] + (-0.27201283) * imgYIQ[:, :, 1] + (-0.64720424) * imgYIQ[:, :, 2]
    RGB[:, :, 2] = 1.00000002 * imgYIQ[:, :, 0] + (-1.10674021) * imgYIQ[:, :, 1] + 1.70423049 * imgYIQ[:, :, 2]

    return RGB
    pass
```

**BUT** it's not a valid answer in my class, any idea's on how to make it in a single step?

Answer (score 2):

Well after many trial and error I have found a solution.

```
def transformRGB2YIQ(imgRGB: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Converts an RGB image to YIQ color space
    :param imgRGB: An Image in RGB
    :return: A YIQ in image color space
    """
    yiq_from_rgb = np.array([[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],
                             [0.59590059, -0.27455667, -0.32134392],
                             [0.21153661, -0.52273617, 0.31119955]])
    OrigShape=imgRGB.shape
    return np.dot(imgRGB.reshape(-1,3), yiq_from_rgb.transpose()).reshape(OrigShape)

    pass


def transformYIQ2RGB(imgYIQ: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Converts an YIQ image to RGB color space
    :param imgYIQ: An Image in YIQ
    :return: A RGB in image color space
    """
    yiq_from_rgb = np.array([[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],
                             [0.59590059, -0.27455667, -0.32134392],
                             [0.21153661, -0.52273617, 0.31119955]])
    OrigShape=imgYIQ.shape
    return np.dot(imgYIQ.reshape(-1,3), np.linalg.inv(yiq_from_rgb).transpose()).reshape(OrigShape)

    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert from RGB to YIQ using numpy's [matmul](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) which is able to perform matrix multiplication on each pixel of the image. Note I am using numpy 1.24.3. The [dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) function also works, in this case it computes a sum product over each pixel. See docs for more details.

`If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b`

The code below has both implementations.

```
def rgb2yiq(image_rgb):
    """ Converts an RGB image to YIQ colorspace
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ
        http://www.progmat.uaem.mx:8080/artVol2Num2/Articulo3Vol2Num2.pdf
        """
    
    rgb2yiq_arr = np.array([[0.29889531, 0.5866247, 0.11448223],
                            [0.59597799, -0.27417610, -0.32180189],
                            [0.21147017, -0.52261711, 0.31114694]])
    
    return image_rgb @ rgb2yiq_arr # same as matmul
    return np.matmul(image_rgb, rgb2yiq_arr)
    # return np.dot(image_rgb, rgb2yiq_arr)



def yiq2rgb(image_yiq):
    """ Converts an RGB image to YIQ colorspace
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ
        http://www.progmat.uaem.mx:8080/artVol2Num2/Articulo3Vol2Num2.pdf
        """
    
    yiq2rgb_arr = np.array([[1.0, 0.95608445, 0.62088850],
                            [1.0, -0.27137664, -0.64860590],
                            [1.0, -1.10561724, 1.70250126]])
    
    return image_yiq @ yiq2rgb_arr # same as matmul
    # return np.matmul(image_yiq, yiq2rgb_arr)
    # return np.dot(image_yiq, yiq2rgb_arr)
```